# How to receive a Json array in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, arrays

I have an asp.net webserver that I am using to try and receive data from a client in the form of a Json array.  A small example:

```
[{"Event":"Connect","Result":"Success"}]
```

Trying a test run though through POSTMAN I receive a 500 error.

> {
>       "Message": "Type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for deserialization of an array.",
>       "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertListToObject(IList list, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, IList& convertedList)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)",
>       "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException"
>   }

I have tried calling an empty web method and I am still receiving the error which is throwing me off since I havent done anything with the object yet.
Here are the two methods I have tried calling, the first one is just an empty method, the second is what I was using before I found out I needed to receive a json array.

```
[WebMethod(Description = "test")]
public void TEST()
{

}
```

```
[WebMethod(Description="Webhook")]
public void Webhook()
{
    string message = null;
    var req = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
    req.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string body = req.ReadToEnd().ToString();
    // Parse through json object and do things
}
```

Comment: Your Json contains an array that contains a dictionary. How are you trying to deserialize this? It would seem you tried to deserialize it into a Dictionary instead of an Array of dictionaries (eg `Dictionary<string,string>[]`). Please post your DTO and the code you use to deserialize the data

Comment: Thats the thing I havent tried to deserialize anything yet.  This error is thrown before any break points could be hit.

Comment: The deserializer is already called, either explicitly or implicitly because you tried to deserialize to a specific object. Either your json is wrong (you didn't actually want to use an array) or you should deserialize to an array of Dictionaries/objects. Please post the code

Comment: Can you try to see what the 500 error is exactly? This is just a generic server error indicator.  Try putting a breakpoint in your Application_Error event in the Global.asax file to find the exact error which is occurring.

Comment: Added a breakpoint to Application_Error and it was never hit.

Comment: I added the code into the original post.

Comment: I tested some more with Postman and giving the json array a name lets the message pass through.

Comment: Hello, did any one here got the solution for this issue. Please share.

Comment: Hi Pratik, Its been awhile since I worked on that project so I dont know the exact details but I do remember that I created a small php script infront of the asp.net service to receive the json.  I suspect that IIS was trying to interact with the json message before it actually hit any of my methods. Since the json message did not have a name IIS freaked out and threw an exception.  To get around this I put a small php script that would receive the json message.  I then changed the content-type to plain text and posted the message back to my asp.net service.